# Quality of Service : remote login requirements for handling jitter

Tags: networking, qos, jitter

I'm currently studying for my upcoming examination of Computer Networks and am covering the section "Quality of Service". Here, a table is shown displaying requirements by application in terms of bandwith, delay, jitter and loss.

To clarify with a simple example:

```
APP          |    BANDWIDTH    DELAY    JITTER    LOSS
-------------+------------------------------------------
Email        |      low         low      low     medium
File share   |      high        low      low     medium
  ...
```

I understand all but one of the examples provided in the book: remote login.

```
Remote login |      low        medium   medium    low
```

It is unclear to me why jitter is a 'medium requirement' to be considered when implementing a remote login system. As far as my understanding goes: jitter is an irregularity in the time base of a signal, which (when applied to networking) can cause variable delays in delivering packets. I can understand the importance of this in applications revolving around telephony, video-conferencing, etc., but am having trouble to understand its importance in remote login systems.

Any thoughts/help is (always) greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, I read some more on the matter and found the following:

(Keeping in mind that we know that if our application is sensitive to jitter, it will definitely be subject to delay.)

> "Remote control and login are very delay sensitive. Typically a user expects responsiveness on the order of tens of milliseconds during a remote login session."
>
> *Internetworking and Computing Over Satellite Networks*  (Y. Zhang)
>
> "Since remote login should be characterised by high reliability, no bits must be affected by errors. To accomplish this, checks are carried out at destination and, in the event of an error, confirmation of correct recept is not sent, an event that causes the transmitter to resend the packet that incorrectly reached the destination. ... In general, remote login, and in particular audio and video on demand, telephony and video conferencing are, however, sensitive to jitter."
>
> *Handbook of Communications Security* (F. Garzia)

This confirms the straightforward assumptions which were also made by @CX gamer in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that jitter also causes out-of-order packages. While not strictly necessary for remote login applications, it does help if the returned output is in-order. Perhaps therefore, it's not useful to spend a lot of resources ensuring low litter, but small pay-offs are worth it.